# Create ZIP file with fopen() wrapper

Tags: php, zip, wrapper

How can you create a ZIP file using the [fopen() wrapper](http://es.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php)? This is obviously *not* the way:

```
<?php

if( class_exists('ZipArchive') ){
    echo 'Class ZipArchive exists, generating file...' . PHP_EOL;

    $fp = fopen('zip://' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/test.zip', 'w');
    if($fp){
        fwrite($fp, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.');
        fclose($fp);
        echo 'Done' . PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        echo 'Could not open file' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}else{
    echo 'Class Zip is not available' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

... because all I get is:

```
Class ZipArchive exists, generating file...

Warning: fopen(zip://C:\tmp/test.zip) [http://es.php.net/function.fopen]: failed to open stream: operation failed in C:\tmp\test.php on line 6
Could not open file
```

Comment: Is there a reason, why you dont use the `ZipArchive` class? Does `c:\tmp` exists and it is writeable for the user?

Comment: @KingCrunch - I'm trying to feed $fp into some third-party code that accepts a file pointer as parameter. Code works as expected if I remove the `zip://` part from the fopen() call so permissions are okay.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-getstream.php 
should be installedfrom pecl

Comment: @Fivell - «Get a file handler to the entry defined by its name. For now it only supports read operations.» :-?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally assumed that the claim that `zip:` wrapper supports writing was a documentation error and [reported it as such](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54515). The bug report was accepted and fixed.